# Electron - Linux - blank screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron

I have a very basic application that is coded under windows and work perfectly.

I now want to test it on my raspberry pi (raspbian). I did the package (targetting linux armv7l).  I made the main file executable (chmod +x myfile) and then run it (./myfile). Electron start without problem but i only have a white page (like if no html/js was loading). Ive got no error at all...

Is there a way i can debug? Anyone already add this issue? I did try with electron@1.8.3 and electron@2.0.0. The ui part is with Vue.

Here is the code (small project, just a playground) if someone want to have a look : https://github.com/doumlap/shineos

Comment: To debug: Disable one module after another to identify the module which is causing issues. You can focus on modules which include c components.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running latest Electron 3.x.x, and I had similar issue.

I did it working by using `electron main.js --disable-gpu`

Answer (score 5):

Another option apart of --disable-gpu argument is disabling it in electron main.js.

https://electronjs.org/docs/all#appdisablehardwareacceleration

```
if (process.platform === 'linux') {
    app.disableHardwareAcceleration();
}
```